# Maximo Anywhere Not Able To login

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, maximo, maximo-anywhere

I have Maximo Anywhere installed on WebSphere 8.5.5.3 and Maximo installed in Weblogic
i am not able to login to anywhere apps
i tried to debug it from chrome console i found its stuck on loop as the below

```
>    worklight.js:4675 Request [login]
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] ServerAuthenticationProvider.login
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [CustomChallangeHandler.isCustomResponse] true - authStatus
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [ServerAuthenticationProvider] User test successfully authentication against realm "CustomAuthenticationRealm"
worklight.js:4675 Request [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query]
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [CustomChallangeHandler.isCustomResponse] false
worklight.js:4675 response [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query] success: /*-secure-
{"isSuccessful":true,"userId":"test","attributes":{"Cookie":"JSESSIONID=0000NpUyrxPJPTCpeahWtAKZ-xr:-1; Path=\/","AuthenticationDate":"Wed Jul 08 03:07:48 GST 2015"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"responseID":"149252","displayName":null}*/
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] User test authenticated successfully on server
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [COMM] Previous "userInfo" resource data request resolved.
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [COMM] Getting data from adapter if connectivity is available.
Logger.js:231 [TIMER] [COMM] Fetching simulator for connectivity: 1ms
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [COMM] Connectivity is available
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [COMM] Requesting data for adapter
Logger.js:151 [COMM] resourceUrl: http://192.168.1.31:7001/maximo/oslc/os/oslcmaxuser?savedQuery=currentUser&…Bspi%3Agroupname%7D&oslc.pageSize=300&oslc.orderBy=%2Bdcterms%3Aidentifier
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Invoking adapter with these parameters: {"adapter":"OSLCGenericAdapter","procedure":"query","parameters":[{"url":"http://192.168.1.31:7001/maximo/oslc/os/oslcmaxuser?savedQuery=currentUser&…Bspi%3Agroupname%7D&oslc.pageSize=300&oslc.orderBy=%2Bdcterms%3Aidentifier","sessionid":"JSESSIONID=0000NpUyrxPJPTCpeahWtAKZ-xr:-1; Path=/","langcode":"en-US"}],"timeout":360000}
worklight.js:4675 Request [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query]
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [CustomChallangeHandler.isCustomResponse] false
worklight.js:4675 response [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query] success: /*-secure-
{"isSuccessful":false,"errors":[{"oslc:extendedError":{"oslc:moreInfo":{"rdf:resource":"http:\/\/192.168.1.31:7001\/maximo\/oslc\/error\/messages\/BMXAA0021E04"}},"oslc:message":"BMXAA0021E04 - User name and password combination are not valid. Try again.","oslc:statusCode":"401","spi:reasonCode":"BMXAA0021E04"}],"responseID":"149253"}*/
worklight.js:4675 Procedure invocation error. [object Object]WL.Logger.__log @ worklight.js:4675PUBLIC_API.(anonymous function) @ worklight.js:4860onInvokeProcedureSuccess @ worklight.js:7353window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onSuccess @ worklight.js:3240window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onWlSuccess @ worklight.js:3212(anonymous function) @ worklight.js:949window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.respondToReadyState @ worklight.js:1158window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.onStateChange @ worklight.js:1096(anonymous function) @ worklight.js:949
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] UserAuthenticationManager.invokeAdapterSecurely: onFailure{"status":200,"invocationContext":null,"errorCode":"PROCEDURE_ERROR","errorMsg":"Procedure invocation error. [object Object]","invocationResult":{"isSuccessful":false,"errors":[{"oslc:extendedError":{"oslc:moreInfo":{"rdf:resource":"http://192.168.1.31:7001/maximo/oslc/error/messages/BMXAA0021E04"}},"oslc:message":"BMXAA0021E04 - User name and password combination are not valid. Try again.","oslc:statusCode":"401","spi:reasonCode":"BMXAA0021E04"}],"responseID":"149253"}}
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Session for user test expired
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Reauthenticating
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Authenticating user test against realm CustomAuthenticationRealm
Logger.js:231 [TIMER] [COMM] Fetching simulator for connectivity: 0ms
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] ServerAuthenticationProvider.login
worklight.js:4675 Request [login]
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] ServerAuthenticationProvider.login
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [CustomChallangeHandler.isCustomResponse] true - authStatus
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [ServerAuthenticationProvider] User test successfully authentication against realm "CustomAuthenticationRealm"
worklight.js:4675 Request [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query]
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [CustomChallangeHandler.isCustomResponse] false
worklight.js:4675 response [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query] success: /*-secure-
{"isSuccessful":true,"userId":"test","attributes":{"Cookie":"JSESSIONID=0000NpUyrxPJPTCpeahWtAKZ-xr:-1; Path=\/","AuthenticationDate":"Wed Jul 08 03:07:48 GST 2015"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"responseID":"149254","displayName":null}*/
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] User test authenticated successfully on server
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [COMM] Previous "userInfo" resource data request resolved.
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [COMM] Getting data from adapter if connectivity is available.
Logger.js:231 [TIMER] [COMM] Fetching simulator for connectivity: 0ms
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [COMM] Connectivity is available
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [COMM] Requesting data for adapter
Logger.js:151 [COMM] resourceUrl: http://192.168.1.31:7001/maximo/oslc/os/oslcmaxuser?savedQuery=currentUser&…Bspi%3Agroupname%7D&oslc.pageSize=300&oslc.orderBy=%2Bdcterms%3Aidentifier
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Invoking adapter with these parameters: {"adapter":"OSLCGenericAdapter","procedure":"query","parameters":[{"url":"http://192.168.1.31:7001/maximo/oslc/os/oslcmaxuser?savedQuery=currentUser&…Bspi%3Agroupname%7D&oslc.pageSize=300&oslc.orderBy=%2Bdcterms%3Aidentifier","sessionid":"JSESSIONID=0000NpUyrxPJPTCpeahWtAKZ-xr:-1; Path=/","langcode":"en-US"}],"timeout":360000}
worklight.js:4675 Request [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query]
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [CustomChallangeHandler.isCustomResponse] false
worklight.js:4675 response [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query] success: /*-secure-
{"isSuccessful":false,"errors":[{"oslc:extendedError":{"oslc:moreInfo":{"rdf:resource":"http:\/\/192.168.1.31:7001\/maximo\/oslc\/error\/messages\/BMXAA0021E04"}},"oslc:message":"BMXAA0021E04 - User name and password combination are not valid. Try again.","oslc:statusCode":"401","spi:reasonCode":"BMXAA0021E04"}],"responseID":"149255"}*/
worklight.js:4675 Procedure invocation error. [object Object]WL.Logger.__log @ worklight.js:4675PUBLIC_API.(anonymous function) @ worklight.js:4860onInvokeProcedureSuccess @ worklight.js:7353window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onSuccess @ worklight.js:3240window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onWlSuccess @ worklight.js:3212(anonymous function) @ worklight.js:949window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.respondToReadyState @ worklight.js:1158window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.onStateChange @ worklight.js:1096(anonymous function) @ worklight.js:949
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] UserAuthenticationManager.invokeAdapterSecurely: onFailure{"status":200,"invocationContext":null,"errorCode":"PROCEDURE_ERROR","errorMsg":"Procedure invocation error. [object Object]","invocationResult":{"isSuccessful":false,"errors":[{"oslc:extendedError":{"oslc:moreInfo":{"rdf:resource":"http://192.168.1.31:7001/maximo/oslc/error/messages/BMXAA0021E04"}},"oslc:message":"BMXAA0021E04 - User name and password combination are not valid. Try again.","oslc:statusCode":"401","spi:reasonCode":"BMXAA0021E04"}],"responseID":"149255"}}
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Session for user test expired
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Reauthenticating
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Authenticating user test against realm CustomAuthenticationRealm
Logger.js:231 [TIMER] [COMM] Fetching simulator for connectivity: 0ms
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] ServerAuthenticationProvider.login
worklight.js:4675 Request [login]
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] ServerAuthenticationProvider.login
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [CustomChallangeHandler.isCustomResponse] true - authStatus
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [ServerAuthenticationProvider] User test successfully authentication against realm "CustomAuthenticationRealm"
worklight.js:4675 Request [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query]
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [CustomChallangeHandler.isCustomResponse] false
worklight.js:4675 response [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query] success: /*-secure-
{"isSuccessful":true,"userId":"test","attributes":{"Cookie":"JSESSIONID=0000NpUyrxPJPTCpeahWtAKZ-xr:-1; Path=\/","AuthenticationDate":"Wed Jul 08 03:07:48 GST 2015"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"responseID":"149256","displayName":null}*/
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] User test authenticated successfully on server
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [COMM] Previous "userInfo" resource data request resolved.
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [COMM] Getting data from adapter if connectivity is available.
Logger.js:231 [TIMER] [COMM] Fetching simulator for connectivity: 1ms
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [COMM] Connectivity is available
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [COMM] Requesting data for adapter
Logger.js:151 [COMM] resourceUrl: http://192.168.1.31:7001/maximo/oslc/os/oslcmaxuser?savedQuery=currentUser&…Bspi%3Agroupname%7D&oslc.pageSize=300&oslc.orderBy=%2Bdcterms%3Aidentifier
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Invoking adapter with these parameters: {"adapter":"OSLCGenericAdapter","procedure":"query","parameters":[{"url":"http://192.168.1.31:7001/maximo/oslc/os/oslcmaxuser?savedQuery=currentUser&…Bspi%3Agroupname%7D&oslc.pageSize=300&oslc.orderBy=%2Bdcterms%3Aidentifier","sessionid":"JSESSIONID=0000NpUyrxPJPTCpeahWtAKZ-xr:-1; Path=/","langcode":"en-US"}],"timeout":360000}
worklight.js:4675 Request [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query]
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [CustomChallangeHandler.isCustomResponse] false
worklight.js:4675 response [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query] success: /*-secure-
{"isSuccessful":false,"errors":[{"oslc:extendedError":{"oslc:moreInfo":{"rdf:resource":"http:\/\/192.168.1.31:7001\/maximo\/oslc\/error\/messages\/BMXAA0021E04"}},"oslc:message":"BMXAA0021E04 - User name and password combination are not valid. Try again.","oslc:statusCode":"401","spi:reasonCode":"BMXAA0021E04"}],"responseID":"149257"}*/
worklight.js:4675 Procedure invocation error. [object Object]WL.Logger.__log @ worklight.js:4675PUBLIC_API.(anonymous function) @ worklight.js:4860onInvokeProcedureSuccess @ worklight.js:7353window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onSuccess @ worklight.js:3240window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.onWlSuccess @ worklight.js:3212(anonymous function) @ worklight.js:949window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.respondToReadyState @ worklight.js:1158window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.onStateChange @ worklight.js:1096(anonymous function) @ worklight.js:949
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] UserAuthenticationManager.invokeAdapterSecurely: onFailure{"status":200,"invocationContext":null,"errorCode":"PROCEDURE_ERROR","errorMsg":"Procedure invocation error. [object Object]","invocationResult":{"isSuccessful":false,"errors":[{"oslc:extendedError":{"oslc:moreInfo":{"rdf:resource":"http://192.168.1.31:7001/maximo/oslc/error/messages/BMXAA0021E04"}},"oslc:message":"BMXAA0021E04 - User name and password combination are not valid. Try again.","oslc:statusCode":"401","spi:reasonCode":"BMXAA0021E04"}],"responseID":"149257"}}
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Session for user test expired
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Reauthenticating
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Authenticating user test against realm CustomAuthenticationRealm
Logger.js:231 [TIMER] [COMM] Fetching simulator for connectivity: 0ms
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] ServerAuthenticationProvider.login
```

*i tried to call the OSLC Link direct from Maximo its working fine. 
*i tried to run the application from eclipse and using Librity server it working fine .

I Restarted the Server where Work-light installed the exception changed to

```
Authentication (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:303:23)
    at Object.lang.mixin.login (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:133:10)
    at declare.loginClickHandler (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/handlers/LoginHandler.js:72:47)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/UserInterface.js:757:47)
    at HTMLButtonElement.e.hitch (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:34:484)
    at Function.g.emit (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:106:485)
    at declare.fire (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojox/gesture/Base.js:306:7)"l @ dojo.js:59h @ dojo.js:59k.around.advice @ dojo.js:95e.(anonymous function).k @ dojo.js:94m @ dojo.js:89q.reject @ dojo.js:92a @ dojo.js:90g @ dojo.js:89o.then.b.then @ dojo.js:92classBody._activateCollections @ PersistenceManager.js:303classBody.activateCollectionsOrFail @ PersistenceManager.js:284lang.mixin._localAuthentication @ UserAuthenticationManager.js:303lang.mixin.login @ UserAuthenticationManager.js:133declare.loginClickHandler @ LoginHandler.js:72(anonymous function) @ UserInterface.js:757e.hitch @ dojo.js:34g.emit @ dojo.js:106declare.fire @ Base.js:306declare.release @ tap.js:104declare._process @ Base.js:273e._hitchArgs @ dojo.js:34
Startup.js:42 === Global promise rejection handling ===
Startup.js:43 === handled: true
Startup.js:44 Hiding the "Loading..." message in 8 seconds
Startup.js:42 === Global promise rejection handling ===
Startup.js:43 === handled: false
Startup.js:44 Hiding the "Loading..." message in 8 seconds
dojo.js:59 Object {name: undefined, messageKey: undefined, params: Array[0], stack: "undefined?    at http://localhost:9084/worklight/a…fault/js/platform/handlers/LoginHandler.js:72:47)"} "undefined
    at http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/store/PersistenceManager.js:308:23
    at g (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:89:320)
    at o.then.b.then [as then] (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:92:198)
    at classBody._activateCollections (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/store/PersistenceManager.js:303:4)
    at classBody.activateCollectionsOrFail (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/store/PersistenceManager.js:284:16)
    at Object.lang.mixin._localAuthentication (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:303:23)
    at Object.lang.mixin.login (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:133:10)
    at declare.loginClickHandler (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/handlers/LoginHandler.js:72:47)
    ----------------------------------------
    rejected at a (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:90:226)
    at g (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:89:493)
    at o.then.b.then [as then] (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:92:198)
    at Object.lang.mixin._localAuthentication (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:304:4)
    at Object.lang.mixin.login (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:133:10)
    at declare.loginClickHandler (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/handlers/LoginHandler.js:72:47)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/UserInterface.js:757:47)
    at HTMLButtonElement.e.hitch (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:34:484)
    at Function.g.emit (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:106:485)
    at declare.fire (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojox/gesture/Base.js:306:7)
    ----------------------------------------
Error
    at o.then.b.then [as then] (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:92:143)
    at Object.lang.mixin._localAuthentication (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:304:4)
    at Object.lang.mixin.login (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:133:10)
    at declare.loginClickHandler (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/handlers/LoginHandler.js:72:47)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/UserInterface.js:757:47)
    at HTMLButtonElement.e.hitch (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:34:484)
    at Function.g.emit (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:106:485)
    at declare.fire (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojox/gesture/Base.js:306:7)
    at declare.release (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojox/gesture/tap.js:104:10)
    at declare._process (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojox/gesture/Base.js:273:15)"l @ dojo.js:59h @ dojo.js:59k.around.advice @ dojo.js:95e.(anonymous function).k @ dojo.js:94m @ dojo.js:89q.reject @ dojo.js:92a @ dojo.js:90g @ dojo.js:89o.then.b.then @ dojo.js:92lang.mixin._localAuthentication @ UserAuthenticationManager.js:304lang.mixin.login @ UserAuthenticationManager.js:133declare.loginClickHandler @ LoginHandler.js:72(anonymous function) @ UserInterface.js:757e.hitch @ dojo.js:34g.emit @ dojo.js:106declare.fire @ Base.js:306declare.release @ tap.js:104declare._process @ Base.js:273e._hitchArgs @ dojo.js:34
Startup.js:42 === Global promise rejection handling ===
Startup.js:43 === handled: false
Startup.js:44 Hiding the "Loading..." message in 8 seconds
dojo.js:59 Object {name: undefined, messageKey: undefined, params: Array[0], stack: "undefined?    at http://localhost:9084/worklight/a…fault/js/platform/handlers/LoginHandler.js:72:47)"} "undefined
    at http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/store/PersistenceManager.js:308:23
    at g (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:89:320)
    at o.then.b.then [as then] (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:92:198)
    at classBody._activateCollections (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/store/PersistenceManager.js:303:4)
    at classBody.activateCollectionsOrFail (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/store/PersistenceManager.js:284:16)
    at Object.lang.mixin._localAuthentication (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:303:23)
    at Object.lang.mixin.login (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:133:10)
    at declare.loginClickHandler (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/handlers/LoginHandler.js:72:47)
    ----------------------------------------
    rejected at a (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:90:226)
    at g (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:89:479)
    at o.then.b.then [as then] (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:92:198)
    at classBody._activateCollections (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/store/PersistenceManager.js:303:4)
    at classBody.activateCollectionsOrFail (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/store/PersistenceManager.js:284:16)
    at Object.lang.mixin._localAuthentication (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:303:23)
    at Object.lang.mixin.login (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:133:10)
    at declare.loginClickHandler (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/handlers/LoginHandler.js:72:47)
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/ui/control/UserInterface.js:757:47)
    at HTMLButtonElement.e.hitch (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:34:484)
    ----------------------------------------
undefined"l @ dojo.js:59h @ dojo.js:59k.around.advice @ dojo.js:95e.(anonymous function).k @ dojo.js:94g @ dojo.js:90o.then.b.then @ dojo.js:92lang.mixin._localAuthentication @ UserAuthenticationManager.js:304lang.mixin.login @ UserAuthenticationManager.js:133declare.loginClickHandler @ LoginHandler.js:72(anonymous function) @ UserInterface.js:757e.hitch @ dojo.js:34g.emit @ dojo.js:106declare.fire @ Base.js:306declare.release @ tap.js:104declare._process @ Base.js:273e._hitchArgs @ dojo.js:34
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Authenticating user test1 against realm CustomAuthenticationRealm
Logger.js:231 [TIMER] [COMM] Fetching simulator for connectivity: 0ms
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] ServerAuthenticationProvider.login
Logger.js:231 [TIMER] [COMM] Fetching simulator for connectivity: 1ms
worklight.js:4675 Request [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query]
Startup.js:42 === Global promise rejection handling ===
Startup.js:43 === handled: true
Startup.js:44 Hiding the "Loading..." message in 8 seconds
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [CustomChallangeHandler.isCustomResponse] false
worklight.js:4675 response [/worklight/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/common/query] success: /*-secure-
{"properties":{"si.auth.type":"maximo"},"isSuccessful":true,"responseID":"7"}*/
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [COMM] Successfully returned properties: {"si.auth.type":"maximo"}
worklight.js:4675 Request [login]
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] ServerAuthenticationProvider.login
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] [CustomChallangeHandler.isCustomResponse] true - authStatus
Logger.js:151 [_realmAuthentication] Unable to authenticate user test1 on server
Logger.js:151 Loading message showed by application = true
Logger.js:151 Cancel processing requested
Logger.js:163 [TRACE] Closing local storage
Startup.js:42 === Global promise rejection handling ===
Startup.js:43 === handled: true
Startup.js:44 Hiding the "Loading..." message in 8 seconds
Startup.js:42 === Global promise rejection handling ===
Startup.js:43 === handled: false
Startup.js:44 Hiding the "Loading..." message in 8 seconds
dojo.js:59 Object {oslcError: "null oslcError", errorMsg: "Your user name and password could not be validated. Connect to the server and try again."} "
    ----------------------------------------
    rejected at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/js/platform/auth/UserAuthenticationManager.js:523:17)
    at e.hitch (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:34:484)
    at g (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:89:320)
    at m (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:89:246)
    at q.reject (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:92:33)
    at a (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:90:226)
    at g (http://localhost:9084/worklight/apps/services/preview/WorkExecution/common/0/default/dojo/dojo.js:89:493)
    at m
```

Comment: I Restarted the Server where Work-light installed the exception changed to

Comment: You have a authentication/login error based on  "errorMsg: "Your user name and password could not be validated. Connect to the server and try again." and "oslc:statusCode":"401" .  I don't know much about Anywhere. Can you explain how the authentication to the backend (OSLC oto Maximo) is hapenning ? What is the security test declared in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a authentication/login error based on  "errorMsg: "Your user name and password could not be validated. Connect to the server and try again." and "oslc:statusCode":"401" .  I don't know much about Anywhere. Can you explain how the authentication to the backend (OSLC oto Maximo) is hapenning ? What is the security test declared in for "OSLCGenericAdapter" procedure:"query",?  It seems you are doing a request to "http://192.168.1.31:7001/maximo/oslc/os/oslcmaxuser"   maybe this server is not available ? Are you using some invalid username/pass ?

Comment: Leanrdo Thank you alot 
actually i found the issue it was in AnywhereWorkManager.war file it was pointing to different server

Comment: leandro, we have a custom login module that uses an authenticationConfig.xml file that stores the maximo url information.  It seems like from Mohammed's comment that it was pointing to an old Maximo server.

Answer (score 1):

So you said you restarted the server worklight is installed on. The first thing i would ask then is the war file that you deployed to that server, when it was built, was it pointing to a different Maximo than what your adapter currently has?

If it worked in the liberty server, I would say to update the war file that your worklight server is using, there may be a difference in what it is pointing.

This would involve updating your build.properties' 
worklight.server.* properties, then rebuild the app, and then redeploy the war file that you will have in your MaximoAnywhere/bin directory

Comment: seems like from Mohammed's comment above, that was the culprit, an outdated reference in the authenticationConfig.xml pointed to inside the war file.

Comment: Yes exactly i found that uthenticationConfig.xml is pointing to different server